# Facebook Pixel Tracking Installation in Magento 1.9

Tags: facebook, magento-1.9

I have been trying to implement the new Facebook Tracking Pixel to track conversion in a Magento store.

I have the base pixel code in the head tags

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=    [];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'PIXELID');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=PIXELID&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

I have then found the success.phtml file within the themes directories as added the following code as per my understanding when reading the Facebook documentation I have found;

```
<?php
//Get Order Number & Order Total
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$amount = number_format($order->getGrandTotal(),2);
?>
<script>
// Purchase
// Track purchases or checkout flow completions (ex. landing on "Thank You" or confirmation page)
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {'value': '<?php echo $amount; ?>', 'currency': 'GBP'});
</script>

<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=PIXELID&amp;ev=Purchase&amp;cd[value]=<?php echo $amount; ?>&amp;cd[currency]=GBP&amp;noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
```

The above code isn't sending any data at all upon placing an order via a Facebook ad click.  Can anyone shed any light as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: is there any error or warning in the browser console?

Comment: Nope.  I'm wondering now if the pixel within the ad creation has been set up wrong.  This is something that hasnt been done by me.  I have only been given the code to add into the site itself, but I'm pretty sure that the ad needs to add the conversion pixel id during its creation?

Comment: If you use the Pixel Helper (downloadable from the Chrome plugin store) you should be able to debug where the issue is.